# xsl:when test with CDATA not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Xml is:

```
   <field name="Type">
        <![CDATA[Amount]]>
    </field>
```

Xpath in Xsl is

```
<xsl:when test="node()[@name='Type'] ='Amount'">
```

I am trying to check the value of Type. But it is not working.
Please help.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail to the question, in particular a complete XML and XSLT that demonstrates the problem? Your current syntax is valid, but it really depends on what your current context is when the expression is evaluated. In particular, it would only give you the desired results if you were positioned on the parent of the `field` node. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that your `field` element does not exactly have the string value `Amount` but rather its string value contains `Amount` preceded and followed by white space so either use `normalize-space(field[@name = 'Type']) = 'Amount'` or use `contains(field[@name = 'Type'], 'Amount')`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen. Yes. correct. Thank you very much. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the XML markup

```
   <field name="Type">
        <![CDATA[Amount]]>
    </field>
```

the string contents of the `field` element is not only the word `Amount` but the word `Amount` preceded and followed by white space. So you need to use `normalize-space`

```
normalize-space(field[@name = 'Type']) = 'Amount'
```

or you need to use a `contains` check

```
contains(field[@name = 'Type'], 'Amount')
```